# How to change color of a dynamically created element if a certain condition is true?

Tags: javascript

I have created some dynamic products. What I want is that if the product quantity decrease to for example 3 then turn into orange or if it´s only one left then turn into red.
Here is the javascript of the dynamical products for the admin view:

```
function showProductAdmin() {

      lblProductList.innerHTML = "";

      for ( var i = 0; i < ajProductDataFromServer.length; i++ ) {

          var lblProduct = '<div class="lblProduct">' + '<img src="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '"width="85%" alt="product" class="lblProductImage" data-productImage="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '">' + '<h3 class ="lblProductName" data-productName="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].name + '" >' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].name + '</h3>' + '<h3 class ="lblProductPrice" data-productPrice="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].price + '">' + 'Price:' + ' ' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].price + '<h3 class ="lblProductQuantity" data-productQuantity="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].quantity + '">' + 'Quantity:' + ' ' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].quantity + '</h3>' + '<button id="btnEditProductBody" class="btnShowPage btnEditProduct" data-showThisPage="pageUpdateProduct" data-productId="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].id + '">' + 'EDIT PRODUCT' + '</button>' + '<button class="btnDeleteProduct" data-productId="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].id + '" >' + 'DELETE PRODUCT' + '</button>' + '<h3 class="lblErrorMessage" id="lblDeleteProductErrorMessage">' + '</h3>' + '</div>';

          lblProductList.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', lblProduct );
          showPages();

      }


  }
```

and then for the user view:

```
function showProduct() {

      lblProductList.innerHTML = "";

      for ( var i = 0; i < ajProductDataFromServer.length; i++ ) {

          var lblProduct = '<div class ="lblProduct">' + '<img src="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '" width="85%" alt="product">' + '<h3 class ="lblProductName">' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].name + '</h3>' + '<h3 class ="lblProductPrice">' + 'Price:' + ' ' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].price + '<h3 class ="lblProductQuantity">' + 'Quantity:' + ' ' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].quantity + '</h3>' + '<button class="btnBuyProduct" data-productId="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].id + '" >' + 'BUY PRODUCT' + '</button>' + '</div>';

          lblProductList.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', lblProduct );
      }

  }
```

also here the btnBuyProduct click event:

```
// BUY product for user
  document.addEventListener( "click", function(e) {

      if ( e.target.classList.contains( "btnBuyProduct" ) ) {

          sProductId = e.target.getAttribute( "data-productId" );
          console.log( sProductId );
          var sUrl = "api_buy_product.php?id=" + sProductId;

          var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
          request.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if ( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) {

                  ajProductDataFromServer = JSON.parse( this.responseText );
                  console.log( "Response:" + ajProductDataFromServer );

                  if ( ajProductDataFromServer.buy == "ok" ) {

                      if ( !window.Notification ) {

                          alert( "Sorry, Notification Not supported in this Browser!" );

                      } else {

                          if ( Notification.permission === 'granted' ) {

                              notify = new Notification( 'SHOPAHOLIC.com', {
                                  body: 'The product has been added to your shopping cart!"', // the name of the pruduct
                                  icon: 'img_webshop/Fashion-Logo-6.png' // I could show the respective product image
                              });
                          }
                      }


                      playSound();

                      getajProductData();

                      //console.log( ajProductDataFromServer.quantity );
                      console.log( "PRODUCT QUANTITY DECREASED IN THE DATABASE" );

                  } else {

                      console.log( "PRODUCT QUANTITY DID NOT DECREASE IN THE DATABASE" );
                      lblDeleteProductErrorMessage.innerHTML = "";
                      var sDeleteProductErrorMessage = "Deleting Product Failed - Try again";
                      lblDeleteProductErrorMessage.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', sDeleteProductErrorMessage );

                  }
              }
          }

          request.open( "GET", "api_buy_product.php?id=" + sProductId, true );
          request.send();

      }

  });
```

What would be the simpliest way to update this color change for both admin and user view?

Comment: P.S: I would also like that only the number it gets a color and not the whole h3 element.

Answer (score 0):

When displaying products amount, wrap the number into the `<span>` element, and based on the `ajProductDataFromServer[i].quantity`, add matching classes to the wrapping `<span>`:

CSS:

```
span.orange { color: orange; }
span.red { color: red; }
span.green { color: green }
```

In your `showProduct()`:

1) Before the `var lblProduct = ...`, add:

```
var className = '';

if(ajProductDataFromServer[i].quantity > 3) {
    className = 'green';
} else if(ajProductDataFromServer[i].quantity <= 1) {
    className = 'red';
} else {
    className = 'orange';
}
```

or shorter version:

```
var q         = ajProductDataFromServer[i].quantity;
var className = q > 3 ? 'green' : q <= 1 ? 'red' : 'orange';
```

and then, replace this part:

```
'<h3 class ="lblProductQuantity">' + 
    'Quantity:' + ' ' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].quantity + 
'</h3>'
```

with this:

```
'<h3 class ="lblProductQuantity">' + 
    'Quantity:' + 
    ' ' + 
    '<span class=' + className + '>' +
        ajProductDataFromServer[i].quantity + 
    '</span>' +
'</h3>'
```